# What is the type of array pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

When I declare an array in C:

```
char a[] = "something";
```

I understand that **a** is implicitly a const character pointer, i.e. **a** is of the type: `(char * const)`

But then why does the following statement result in the compiler warning about incompatible pointer types?

```
char * const * j = &a;
```

The only way I've managed to get rid of it is by explicitly casting the right hand side to `(char * const *)`.

I hypothesized that `&` operator returns a constant pointer and tried:

```
char * const * const j = &a;
```

without success.

What is going on here?

Comment: `a` is not a pointer, it's an array.  In some situations, it will "decay" to a pointer to `a[0]`, or a `char *`... but `&a` does not give the address of a pointer, it gives the address of the array... which is the same address as `&a[0]`, but a different *type*, as it points to an array and not to a `char`.  `char * const * const j` is a pointer to a pointer, which `&a` is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> char a[] = "something";
> ```
>
> I understand that **a** is implicitly a const character pointer, i.e. **a** is of the type: `(char * const)`

Wrong, `a` is of type (non-const) `char[10]`.

So now that we know `a` is `char[10]`, it's clear why the following doesn't compile:

```
char * const * j = &a;
```

`&a` is of type `char(*)[10]` (i.e. pointer to `char[10]`). `char(*)[10]` and `char * const *` are completely unrelated.

---

If you wrote `char* a = "something";`, then `a` would be a `char*`.

Comment: Then does `char * const k = a;` convert silently?

Comment: Yes, that is known as [array-to-pointer decay](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3425536).

Comment: Oh..that explains. I thought array and pointer were internally represented the same way.

Comment: Ah not at all. A pointer is represented as an integer, whereas an array is represented as a sequence of objects.

Comment: Hmmm...so after all the checks are done on compilation; at run time, are the array access operations just doing pointer arithmetic? Or is there something more to it? Or is that left up to the compiler?